# Jenkins pipeline job, para subir container docker, não está funcionando

Tags: docker, jenkins

Estou executando em uma máquina local, apenas para estudo, no Windows 7

Estou com um projeto no Jenkins (pipeline), que sobe uma imagem docker, porém quando construo a build, está me retornando este erro:

```
java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:249)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:218)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:929)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:449)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:460)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.impl.RegistryKeyMaterialFactory.materialize(RegistryKeyMaterialFactory.java:72)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.AbstractEndpointStepExecution.start(AbstractEndpointStepExecution.java:45)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:229)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:153)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker": CreateProcess error=2, O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:249)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:218)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:929)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:449)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:460)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.impl.RegistryKeyMaterialFactory.materialize(RegistryKeyMaterialFactory.java:72)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.AbstractEndpointStepExecution.start(AbstractEndpointStepExecution.java:45)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:229)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:153)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker.withRegistry(jar:file:/C:/Jenkins/plugins/docker-workflow/WEB-INF/lib/docker-workflow.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy:40)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor328.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Finished: FAILURE
```

**"Cannot run program "docker"**:

Após várias pesquisas, a maioria indica como resultado instalar o docker na máquina local, pois é para ela que o jenkins vai olhar. No entanto, minha máquina já possui docker e ele funciona normalmente, conforme saída do comando abaixo:

```
$ docker info
Containers: 131
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 130
Images: 188
Server Version: 18.05.0-ce
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 427
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 773c489c9c1b21a6d78b5c538cd395416ec50f88
runc version: 4fc53a81fb7c994640722ac585fa9ca548971871
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.9.93-boot2docker
Operating System: Boot2Docker 18.05.0-ce (TCL 8.2.1); HEAD : b5d6989 - Thu May 10 16:35:28 UTC 2018
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 995.6MiB
Name: default
ID: A3OP:HSIS:MQOH:NX66:6VWA:4KB7:SPNZ:XPOP:2RWO:IBCR:4QMO:GJMM
Docker Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
 provider=virtualbox
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

E:

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24302
```

Comment: O jenkins está local e não num container docker, correto? Todos os usuários tem acesso ao docker? O usuário que roda o jenkins, consegue também executar o docker? Inclua o _job definition_ do jenkins pra gente ter ideia do que está tentando rodar.

Comment: 1-  Sim o Jenkins está local, e não está em um container. 2 - Só existe o meu usuário, e ele tem livre acesso ao docker. 3 - O usuário do jenkins, foi criado no momento da instalação, e é diferente do usuário de acesso a máquina. 4 - Foi criada uma biblioteca compartilhada, com o código groovy. Então o job definition, faz apenas uma chamada desta biblioteca, mas no caso ela não é o problema, pois testando em uma outra máquina funciona normalmente, apenas nesta máquina não ... Queria tentar identificar o motivo, desde já, grato pelo seu retorno!

Comment: Fiz um teste, criando um projeto no Jenkins, apenas para rodar o comando docker -v, e ver se funciona, e o resultado foi: 



C:\Jenkins\workspace\teste_doc_func [teste_doc_func] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins4923908087030268188.bat C:\Jenkins\workspace\teste_doc_func>docker -v 'docker' nÆo ‚ reconhecido como um comando interno ou externo, um programa oper vel ou um arquivo em lotes. C:\Jenkins\workspace\teste_doc_func>exit 9009 Build step 'Executar no comando do Windows' marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Não me refiro ao usuário de acesso ao jenkins ou à máquina, mas sim o usuário que está rodando o processo do jenkins/jvm. Não sei como é no windows, acredito que por padrão apenas o usuário que instalou pode rodar o docker - como por padrão apenas usuário com permissão _root_ roda no unix. Pelo erro é possível que seja isto, permissão de usuário, que é como aqui no unix também. Se não for permissão, mas ainda assim usuário diferente, veja se o docker está nas variáveis de ambiente.

Comment: Resolvido o problema: Foi necessário configurar as variáveis de ambiente do docker no Windows. Obrigado pela sua ajuda.